# Signaling game (beer and quiche) and consistent beliefs

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, signaling

[image: Solution to belief]

[image: Game]

I am confused why the top left node has numerator (9/10x1/9) instead of (1/10x1/9) since this should be the probability of reaching this node given the strategies? Same with upper right node, why is not 1/10x8/9?

Comment: Naming the source where this calculation is given is useful both for future readers and potential answerers.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that there is a typo in the Figure; if Nature goes way $S$ with probabilty $1/10$ the calculations and results are consistent.

Hard to validate since original text of the problem or reference to where it can be found is not given.